# chromeのエクステンションの開発

Tags: javascript

自分がyoutubeにアップロードしている動画をボタン１つで、Aというサイト（自分が所有しているサイト）にアップロードできるchrome拡張機能を作ることは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 可能です。少なくとも方法は思いつきます。しかし、質問が曖昧すぎて何を回答して良いのかわかりません。何が知りたいか具体化できないでしょうか？ [良い質問をするには? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: 回答して頂き、ありがとうございます。上記のようなことを行うには、一度ローカルに保存したものを、再度、Aにアップロードするというフローでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Youtubeの形式のままでは保存できない(できても再生できない)ので、なんらかのエンコーディングをかける必要があると思います。
出来るか出来ないかで言えばもちろん出来るのでしょうが、簡単に作れる気もしないです。
（リンク埋め込みじゃなくてアップロードですよね？）

Chrome拡張でやるよりは、 youtube-dl 等のほうが良いのではないでしょうか。